# In ElasticSearch, removed stop words continue to have a small effect on scoring

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Base Match Query: Billy Sue

Test Match Query #1: Billy Sue and

Test Match Query #2: Billy and Sue

We end up with identical scores between Base and #1, but Base and #2 have similar yet different scores.

Using the analyze API, the stop word `and` is removed on both test queries, but the start_offset and end_offset token properties differ for `Sue` between the Base query and Test Query #2.

Essentially, the pre-stop-word-removal distance between the remaining tokens is recorded and has a small yet finite impact on scoring.

**The Question**

Is there a way to delay the calculation of the `start_offset` and `end_offset` properties of tokens until after stop-words are removed, or otherwise prevent removed stop-words from influencing scoring in any fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps disable [position increments](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/stop-tokenfilter.html)  on the stop word filterand see if that helps?  Especially if your mapping has some kind of filter after the stop word filter, you'll get strange artifacts from the position increments

E.g. something like this:

```
"analyzer": {
   "analyzer_example":{
      "tokenizer":"standard",
      "filter":["standard", "lowercase", "filter_stop"]
    }
},
"filter": { 
   "filter_stop":{
      "type":"stop",
      "enable_position_increments":"false"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I overlooked that option. It has been staring me in the face several times this morning as I've viewed that specific page. Thanks for the perfect answer!

Comment: This does not work in a newer version, see http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Enable-Position-Increments-property-not-available-td4048950.html